# Problem deleting records with one query in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

When I try this directly in phpMyAdmin:

```
DELETE FROM navigation WHERE id='14';DELETE FROM subnavigation WHERE navi_id='14';
```

It works but when I it doesnt work with my PHP query that I make:

```
$db->query('DELETE FROM navigation WHERE id='.$id.';DELETE FROM subnavigation WHERE navi_id='.$id.';');
```

It gives me this error and doesnt delete anything:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM
>   subnavigation WHERE navi_id=14' at
>   line 1

I think that I am missing something really small! 
Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it one query.

```
//don't forget to protect yourself from SQL-injection attacks!
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);

$delete_query = " DELETE n, sn from navigation n
                  LEFT JOIN subnavigation sn ON (n.id = sn.id)
                  WHERE n.id = '$id' ");
$db->query($delete_query);
```

Comment: thank you for this I am going to try this, and for now I am not protecting anything from SQL injection because I am not using it live yet, I am going to close all holes when everything will be able to do its job

EDIT: I did used your idea and I dont think that I am going to change it anytime soon unless I find a little bit more speed with another idea.
Thank you for your help

Comment: @TooCool i would suggest that you always code to protect against SQL injection. You might accidentally leave one hole and that is enough to get your site compromised.

Comment: @TooCool, definitly put in de SQL-protection code from the start. The amount of grief that you suffer if you even forget one of these babies is **not** worth it!!

Answer (score 2):

mysql_query() sends a unique query (**multiple queries are not supported**) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

PhpMyAdmin explodes the string based on the delimiter and executes as multiple queries.

If you want to go off the book (not recommended)

You just have to pass flag 65536 as mysql_connect's 5 parameter (client_flags). This value is defined in `/usr/include/mysql/mysql_com.h`:

```
#define CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS (1UL << 16) /* Enable/disable multi-stmt support */
```

**UPDATE**

Create a trigger on the first table, so ON DELETE it will also delete from the 2nd table too.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this in the best way, because I dont want to write it down two times! (to do the query two times). I would like to do it in one query but to delete records from 2 different tables.. so what is the best and proper way

Comment: The elegant and failsafe solution would be a Trigger, see my update.

Comment: -1 Overly complicated, and you haven't mentioned ON DELETE CASCADE foreign keys, which sounds like a much simpler concept.

Comment: That field is not a foreign key, it's a primary key of the current table, you can't set foreign key based on that, so ON DELETE CASCADE doesn't work out, only much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple statements like that are not a query, they form a script.  Look into submitting SQL scripts.
http://www.shinephp.com/php-code-to-execute-mysql-script/